# OpenGL supports only the default graphics adapter

Tags: opengl, graphics, oculus

For some reason I can no longer run the OculusRoomTiny sample program anymore because I keep getting this pop up "OpenGL supports only the default graphics adapter."

It's being triggered by this code shown below in main.cpp:

```
 if (Compare(luid, GetDefaultAdapterLuid())) // If luid that the Rift is on is not the default adapter LUID...
    {
        VALIDATE(false, "OpenGL supports only the default graphics adapter.");
    }
```

and

```
static ovrGraphicsLuid GetDefaultAdapterLuid()
{
    ovrGraphicsLuid luid = ovrGraphicsLuid();

    #if defined(_WIN32)
        IDXGIFactory* factory = nullptr;

        if (SUCCEEDED(CreateDXGIFactory(IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory))))
        {
            IDXGIAdapter* adapter = nullptr;

            if (SUCCEEDED(factory->EnumAdapters(0, &adapter)))
            {
                DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC desc;

                adapter->GetDesc(&desc);
                memcpy(&luid, &desc.AdapterLuid, sizeof(luid));
                adapter->Release();
            }

            factory->Release();
        }
    #endif

    return luid;
}
```

I've never had this issue before, haven't changed any code, reinstalled the SDK, and I still get the same problem - did something happen to my headset - why isn't the luid the same? I'm using the DK2 and SDK 1.9.0

When I comment out the VALIDATE statement, the program runs, but the oculus just gets stuck in the "please wait" screen forever.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I noticed that the app was trying to use my onboard Intel graphics card.
I solved the problem by changing the NVidia driver in windows to make it the default graphics card.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how were you able to change the NVidia driver?

Comment: It's in the NVidia control panel, I got it to work again, thank you!